# Get data from another file? Without jQuery or Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How would I get data from another file. For example a username check:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "check.php", 
    data: "username="+ usr, 
    success: function(msg){ }
)}
```

That example uses ajax, I was wondering how I would do something similar, without any javascript plugin/extension.

Comment: Ajax is supported by most (all?) browsers nowadays. jQuery just provides a nice wrapper around it. You can directly use the API provided by the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,not possible.

```
 $("#randomdiv").load("load.php")
```

Comment: That is jQuery *and* Ajax. The question is looking for something that uses neither.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that without JavaScript.

What you can use is:

- simple XHR request
- iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the file over HTTP, then no — that is, *by definition*, Ajax.

If you are happy getting the file from the user via a `<input type="file">` then you can use [the File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

If, by Ajax, you actually mean "jQuery's `ajax` method", then you can do it directly using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest).